# Morse code encoder decoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, morse-code

I created this morse code encoder and decoder.

```py
class DecodeError(BaseException):
    __module__ = Exception.__module__

class EncodeError(BaseException):
    __module__ = Exception.__module__


code_letter = {
    '.-': 'A', '-...': 'B', '-.-.': 'C', '-..': 'D', '.': 'E', '..-.': 'F', '--.': 'G',
    '....': 'H', '..': 'I', '.---': 'J', '-.-': 'K', '.-..': 'L', '--': 'M', '-.': 'N',
    '---': 'O', '.--.': 'P', '--.-': 'Q', '.-.': 'R', '...': 'S', '-': 'T', '..-': 'U',
    '...-': 'V', '.--': 'W', '-..-': 'X', '-.--': 'Y', '--..': 'Z',

    '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3', '....-': '4', '.....': '5',
    '-....': '6', '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9', '-----': '0',

    '--..--': ', ', '.-.-.-': '.', '..--..': '?', '-..-.': '/',
    '-....-': '-', '-.--.': '(', '-.--.-': ')', '/': ' '
}


letter_code = {value: key for key, value in zip(code_letter.keys(), code_letter.values())}


def morse_encode(string: str) -> str:
    try:
        return ' '.join(letter_code[i.upper()] for i in string)
    except:
        raise EncodeError('Unknown value in string')


def morse_decode(string: str) -> str:
    try:
        return ''.join(code_letter[i] for i in string.split())
    except:
        raise DecodeError('Unknown value in string')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input()
    print(morse_encode(string))
```

Is it possible to make the code shorter while maintaining neatness?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@l0b0 is right for (1.). The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) say to inherit from `Exception` instead:

> The base class for all built-in exceptions. It is not meant to be directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use Exception)

I've also never seen `__module__` used in that case, but if you like to output better, I guess it works fine.

---

`letter_code` can make use of dictionary's [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20items#dict.items) method.

```
zip(code_letter.keys(), code_letter.values())
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
code_letter.items()
```

And just to make it a little clearer what the dictionary comprehension is doing, I might also rename loop variables:

```
letter_code = {letter: morse for morse, letter in code_letter.items()}
```

---

You're using bare `except`s, which is generally a bad idea. If you accidentally typo some other catchable error into the `try`, you'll get `'Unknown value in string'` messages instead of a real error. Specify what exact error you want to catch. I'd also make use of the fact that stringifying a `KeyError` exception tells you what the bad key was. You can print out the exception to tell the user what went wrong exactly

```
def morse_encode(string: str) -> str:
    try:
        return ' '.join(letter_code[i.upper()] for i in string)

    except KeyError as e:
        raise EncodeError(f'Unknown value in string: {e}')

>>> morse_encode("]")
EncodeError: Unknown value in string: ']'
```

And of course, `i` is a bad name for that loop variable. `i` suggests an index, but that's a letter, not an index. This reads much better

```
' '.join(letter_code[char.upper()] for char in string)
```

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

1. I believe [the idiomatic way to declare custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319675/96588) is to inherit from `Exception` rather than `BaseException`, and to just use the no-op `pass` as the class body. I've not seen the `__module__ = Exception.__module__` pattern before, but if that does what it looks like (making the class effectively part of the exceptions module) that's probably going to be misleading. It's not a generic error, after all.
2. It *might* be faster to put both upper and lower case characters in the dict than to use `upper()`. You could test this with [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).
3. If you're processing a big string of Morse code you might want to use an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586073/96588). That way the string is processed one word at a time, rather than having to split the entire text into a list in memory before starting to output anything.
4. Rather than parsing `input()` I would expect this sort of script to either read standard input or to accept a list of file path [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which would each be read and converted.
5. If the script also accepted `--encode` and `--decode` parameters (possibly with `--encode` as the default) it could easily be used to script a conversion of any text.

Comment: For the first point, if `__module__ = Exception.__module__` is removed, the exception is shown as `__main__.(something)`. Else it is shown as `(somthing)`